# Magento. Get products from multiple categories with a combined AND/OR filter

Tags: database, magento

I'm trying to filter products by categories with OR and AND simultaneously.

Let's say I have categories *SALE*, *TESTWINNER*, *FRUITS* and *VEGETABLES*. I want to get the products which are on *SALE* or *TESTWINNERS* from the categories *FRUITS* and *VEGETABLES*.

So the category pseudofilter would be as follows:
(SALE **or** TESTWINNER) **and** (FRUITS **or** VEGETABLES)

I've tried to accomplish this with:

```
   $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

   $catsSaleWinner = [$saleId, $winnerId];
   $catsFruitVeg = [$fruitId, $vegId];
   $collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $catsSaleWinner));
   $collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $catsFruitVeg));
   $collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

.
The mysql query which Magento created seems to be what it should be:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_category_id`.`category_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `at_category_id` ON (at_category_id.`product_id`=e.entity_id)
WHERE (at_category_id.category_id IN('45', '47')) AND (at_category_id.category_id IN('41', '43')) GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id`
```

.

For some reason the result is empty. No products are returned.

If I try leaving the fruitVeg category filter out, it returns the SALE and WINNERS properly.
If I try leaving the saleWinner category filter out, it returns the FRUITS and VEGETABLES properly.

So the OR parts work ok, but the AND part doesn't.

I've been wrestling with this problem for a couple of days. I don't have a clue what to try next and what could be the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please forgive me for any mistakes in etiquette.

Comment: Your etiquette is perfect.  Your question was well researched (for a couple of days!) and didn't assume the volunteers are here to do your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have the entire answer already, the only difference is you must separate the two sets of categories to individual fields.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->joinField('category_1', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinField('category_2', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$catsSaleWinner = [$saleId, $winnerId];
$catsFruitVeg = [$fruitId, $vegId];
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_1', array('in' => $catsSaleWinner));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_2', array('in' => $catsFruitVeg));
$collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

Comment: Dear mother... It actually works! I was already looking into group_concat and what not.

You sir, deserve a kiss!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your join creates a result where each product-category combination has its own row but with a singular category id, so that `(at_category_id.category_id IN('45', '47')) AND (at_category_id.category_id IN('41', '43')` simply cannot find a row which fulfills both conditions at a time.

Might be better to forgo on the join and instead use `->getCategoryIds()` and iterate instead.

Comment: Ah! I think I understand the problem now. I checked the database tables. Sure enough, there's a single row for each category which is assigned to a product. Thanks!  

I have no idea how to solve the problem yet, but at least I know  what the problem is.